# Do you need justification to transform non-normal data

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption

First, a bit of background: I'm currently working on a project at work that produces variable width data.  During a operation qualification I collected a bunch of data at low, nominal, and high levels.  The data is all independent and I have no reason to expect anything but identical distributions part to part as the process is same with minor parameter tweaks (pressure and speed for example).  The majority (15 out of 18 sample populations) passed a Anderson-Darling, but a few data sets did not.  My quality engineer wants me to transform one of these data sets and use a Weibull distribution (which showed a P value of .079) just because there is a slight correlation.  To clarify, the goal is to perform process capability analysis for each data set.

My question(s): Is it okay to blindly transform data even though I have no rationale?  I have always been taught that if you have independent and identically distributed data that the central limit theorem allows you to perform capability analysis on the data as if it were normal, is that incorrect?

Comment: Due to some confusion in these statements, it would be good if you could edit this question to include an explanation of what analyses you intend to perform on these variables. For instance, no amount of iid data from a non-Normal population will produce a Normal sample, but the *sampling distribution* of some *specific statistics,* such as the sample mean, often will become approximately Normal. Which statistic is involved really does matter: for instance, the sampling distribution of the range will never approach a Normal distribution, even when suitably standardized.

Comment: I've added a clarification that I would like to use this data in a Cpk analysis, is that the information you were looking for?